# Neo4j Node creation from cypher query

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

I am using neo4j-jdbc to execute cypher queries to a server version of Neo4j graph database. Is there a way my returned objects are implementing the Node interface? Just like the ExecutionEngine does when is used with the Neo4jEmbeded

Answer (score 0):

No, they are maps, you can return more detail data by returning:

`RETURN {id:id(n),labels:labels(n),data:n) AS node`